# show image from database PHP

Tags: php

How can I show multiple images from database? I already tried but the images don't show up.

**Database**

[image: database]

**Output**

[image: page]

**Code**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="gambar">Foto KTP</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file border" id="ktp1" name="ktp" multiple>
      </div><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="tambah">Proses</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="reset">Hapus</button> 
    <?php 
    
      if(isset($_POST['tambah'])){
        $id_rekening = $_POST['id_rekening'];
        $nama_file = $_FILES['ktp']['name'];
        $foto = $_FILES['ktp']['name'];
        $source = $_FILES['ktp']['tmp_name'];
        $folder = './assets/';

        move_uploaded_file($source, $folder.$nama_file);
        move_uploaded_file($source, $folder.$foto);
        $insert = mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO pelanggan VALUES (NULL, '$id_rekening', '$nama_file, $foto')");
```

Comment: Why are you storing the same file name twice?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your image upload code -- I assume that you have checked the images are in the correct place on the server and that the file names in the database match the image files.

### Problem

Your code doesn't work because you set your images with attributes like:

```
src='assets/daging2.jpeg, daging2.jpeg'
```

When you should be outputting two separate image tags.

```
<img src='assets/daging2.jpeg' ... >
<img src='assets/daging2.jpeg' ... >
```

**Additionally** you should be using prepared statements for any user generated input.

### Updated code

```
$nomor = 1;
$id    = $_GET["id"] ?? NULL;

// Check something was submitted
if( $id ){
    $dapat = $koneksi->prepare("
        SELECT *
        FROM pemesanan
            JOIN pelanggan ON pemesanan.id_pemesanan = pelanggan.id_pemesanan
        WHERE pemesanan.id_pemesanan = ?
    ");
    $dapat->bind_param("i", $id); // Assuming `id` is an integer
    $dapat->execute();
    
    $result = $dapat->get_result();
    
    while ( $data = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        echo "<tr><td>{$data['id_rekening']}</td>";
    
        // Split the string into file names
        $image_array = explode(", ", $data["ktp"]);

        // Output the images
        foreach($image_array as $image){
            echo "<td><img src='assets/{$image}' width='600' height='450'/></td>";
        }
    
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: and how can i store 2 image in different column?

Comment: @AlvinHeryansyah Are you only ever going to have two images? or sometimes more? I expect you'd do 
do better to save them into separate rows not columns?

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: i want to show my code, but i dont undertand where to put it

Answer (score 0):

Based on this what I see you have the $data['ktp'] array with the image name and extension. The reason why you do not see image is that in the img src is 2 times the image and nothing responds to it.
You can try using this for your image:

```
$images_arr = explode(",",$data['ktp']);

foreach($images_arr as $img){
echo '<td><img src="assets/'.$img.'" width="600" height="450" alt=""></td>";
}
```

This will loop the whole array and display the images.

Comment: hi i updated the code, that code i want to store 2 image in 1 column, but just 1 image show up, can you help?

Comment: In that case you can just remove the foreach and just echo it like this :
echo '<td><img src="assets/'.$images_arr['0'].'" width="600" height="450" alt=""></td>";